# Intermittent sound issue with amplifier in Fedora 32

Tags: fedora, pulseaudio, alsa, troubleshooting

To start off, I have no experience writing in this community although I have been around on the SE network for a long time now. I hope my etiquette violations will not be too egregious and you will remain willing to guide me to a suitable answer :).

To get to the heart of the issue: **Sometimes Fedora (32 Workstation, but pre-existed in 31) just refuses to play audio to my amplifier (Analog Output, 3,5mm jack on the motherboard). My headphones (USB) always work, though.**

When I "test" the audio from Settings the sound is played (from Fedora perspective at least, but depending on the mood of the day I hear something or I don't). Sometimes there is a slight pause like something needs to initialise. There is also an issue with it mixing up Analog Output and Digital Audio (S/PDIF) but this is not different in the situations when it works.

The situation (whether good or bad) always persists for as long as the PC remains on. Also logoff/logon doesn't impact it.

---

Possibly irrelevant background information:

When I first installed Fedora there was an issue with the sound being always on 100% and not responding to volume control.

I've done a lot of digging around (over a longer time, unfortunately I don't have all the sources I looked at but most didn't work anyway) and the "solution" which grants me volume control is roughly compatible with the one described [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=225312) (changing `analog-output.conf.common` > Element PCM).

There was also the problem with the sound working intermittently but I didn't manage to source it.

What I found out:

- It helps if the amplifier is turned ON before the computer boots (it's a really old model so I turn it off for its power consumption when not in use)
- `pulseaudio -k` mostly doesn't work, there might have been some instances where it did but I'm not 100% sure (this was suggested to me elsewhere on the internet)
- The `analog-output.conf.common` "solution" has at times been reset through system upgrades reinforcing my suspicion that it is not the way things should be done

As to my background I have been a power user on the Windows platform since the XP era, so don't hesitate to throw in technical stuff -- I want to learn the details of the Linux platform!

---

If you need any output from system commands I am happy to provide you; I didn't include any since my Linux background started after Win 7 went EOL (roughly 1 year ago) and I don't know which commands give meaningful output for troubleshooting.

This situation has been bugging me since I installed Fedora so I would be very grateful if you could help me resolve it!